# How can we disable symbol fade out, fade in effect?

Tags: mapbox, fadein, fadeout, mapbox-gl-js

1. example site
2. https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/

#### Expected Behavior

How can we disable fade in, fade out effect in mapboxgl?

[image]

Comment: I found not documented property.
fadeDuration: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Steve's answer about fading due to the zoom function on opacity. The fading in and out which happens when symbols appear should be able to be controlled via the transition properties either globally or per layer. See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#root-transition

Answer (score 1):

I think the "fade in, fade out" effect you're describing is caused by a layer defined something like this:

```
"icon-opacity": {
    "stops": [[12, 0], [13, 1]]
}
```

That is. At zoom 12, it's 0 opacity, at zoom 13, it's 1 opacity, and at 12.5, it's 0.5 - which looks translucent.

There are several fixes:

- `"minzoom": 13` makes it simply not appear at all below zoom 13 (so no fading)
- Redefining the opacity prop like this, so there is no translucent zone:

`"icon-opacity": { "stops": [[12.9, 0], [13, 1]] }`

- Add `"type": "interval"` so there is no interpolation

I understand that this is a problem for you in a standard style (Mapbox Streets) so you'll have to create a custom version of that style.